# How to manage SQL connection being forcibly closed by the remote host?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, azure-sql-database

We have a long running data integrity checker process that enumerates all rows in a database table and if it detects any differences between the columns then it triggers a sync message to our data warehouse.

The problem I'm having is that during the 6 hours or so it takes to run the SQL connection is randomly closed by the remote host, the error I receive is as follows: -

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

This happens randomly, I have read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/apps-forcibly-closed-tls-connection-errors but I'm running Windows 11 Professional and the SQL database is Azure SQL so I cannot imagine this is the root cause although the symptoms are identical.

Our database access is ADO.NET (not Entity Framework) and we have wrapped all of our database classes and implemented Polly retry policies however, the error reported cannot be recovered from so it simply fails on the maximum number of retries.

I have considered refactoring our loop to enable it to recover from this scenario by tracking the last successful primary key processed and upon failure simply restart the process but only look at records after this tracked value. However, this seems somewhat cumbersome and only works due to our int based primary keys.

How do you implement a resilient long running process that handles transient network failures including the one documented above?

Comment: I'd suggest that having such a long open connection is just bad design. There are so many things that could interrupt a connection that it's bound to happen from time to time. And if it's 6 hours now it doesn't sound sustainable, as your data grows its going to take longer and longer until it takes all day. Database connections are really meant to be short lived. Do you really need to check all data every day? Why not just changed data?

Comment: The symptoms are not identical: the linked article addresses issues establishing connections, but your error message is about interruption of existing connections. Because we log such things I know that we've had SQL Server connections persist for months (i.e.: only interrupted by software updates). I'd suggest to you that if you're not restarting the SQL Server instance, or the server hosting it, then there's probably an issue on your network that's interrupting the connections. Given your client is a desktop-class machine I'd start looking at NAT appliances on your office network.

Comment: @Dale-K The process doesn't run every day, its a utility we run infrequently when needed to check the data integrity of the data.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes you're probably right, I work from home so it is likely something is interrupting it however, I thought the Polly retry would make it more resilient but it appears once the connection is closed it's closed and there's no recovery at that point. Looks like I need to refactor my code to accommodate this as I suggested, just thought I might have been missing something silly! Thanks for the input :-)

Comment: A single long-running process likely won't be benefitted by anything Polly can do since a drop in the SqlConnection will result in the current statement getting rolled back by SQL Server - and if that's a single 6-hour statement then that's a lot of wasted work. Given your connection difficulties trying to break the task up into smaller batches seems like the way to go, as you thought, either tracking current progress on the client side or with tables (not #temp or ##temp tables) on the server-side.

Comment: Consider running this from SQL Server Agent, which will run locally on the server and therefore less prone to connection interruptions.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't always release CUs every month. Regardless, connection uptime is much more than 6 hours.